how to sample time stamped records
I have a data set that has a timestamp column.  What I'm looking for is a select statement that will allow me to collect a result set that contains rows from every x seconds.  For example, consider this table:
bob    05-05-2024 15:00
Ted    05-05-2024 15:06
Alice  05-05-2024 15:07
John   05-05-2024 15:08
Denver 05-05-2024 15:11

Then the result of the query if x is 5 would be:
bob    05-05-2024 15:00
bob    05-05-2024 15:00
John   05-05-2024 15:08
Denver 05-05-2024 15:11

The first row represents the start time.  The second row represents the time start+5 secs.  The third row is start+10, the 4th is start+15.
I could add another column that has the "chunk" time so that the result set would be the latest of all records of chunk time.  That could work for x=5 but not for other values.  I could also keep a timer while writing and just write the index of the last record written every 5 seconds.

I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

why is there two bobs

Bob #1 is a gimme.  2nd bob is because no other records between 15:00 and 15:05. Ted, Alice and John compete for the 15:05-15:10 chunk (john wins). Denver only competitor for the 15:10-15:15 chunk.

Is there some sort of rounding going on?  and are you taking the max row less than 10 5 seconds?  your results don't make sense to me... at time t0 bob exists. at t+5 we would have bob again since no one matches.   at t+10 we have john since it's max but lower than T+10.  Then we have denver at t+15 as it's max >10 but lower than 15...  so you want a mod operator... but your TS doesn't show seconds it shows minutes... so... really confused

Looks like a job for a recursive CTE

Yeah I missed the part where bob was on there twice and needed records for Every 5 interval.  but still stuck on minutes vs seconds myself.

You say +5 secs, but your data has an odd timestamp format where no seconds are included. Column data type?

Using a recursive CTE we can create the 5 second chunks between 2 dates. We can then join with your table to find the row with the max datetime for each chunk.
WITH    CTE (Chunk, sTime ) as
(
  SELECT 1, Cast('05-05-2024 15:00' as DateTime) 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Chunk+1, dateadd(minute,5,sTime)
  FROM CTE
  WHERE  sTime < '05-05-2024 15:15'
),
FoundMaxTS as 
(  
SELECT Chunk, sTime, Max(e.ts) as maxTS
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN Example e ON e.ts between sTime and  dateadd(minute,5,sTime)
GROUP BY CHUNK, sTime
)
SELECT 'Bob' as Name,   Cast('05-05-2024 15:00' as DateTime)  as ts
UNION ALL  
SELECT e.*
FROM Example e
INNER JOIN FoundMaxTS f on f.maxTS = e.ts

fiddle



Chunk
sTime




1
2024-05-05 15:00:00.000


2
2024-05-05 15:05:00.000


3
2024-05-05 15:10:00.000


4
2024-05-05 15:15:00.000






Name
ts




Bob
2024-05-05 15:00:00.000


Bob
2024-05-05 15:00:00.000


John
2024-05-05 15:08:00.000


Denver
2024-05-05 15:11:00.000




We could do something like this:
dbfiddle.uk Demo
.
SELECT A.Name, B.TS 
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN  (SELECT truncate(DATE_FORMAT(TS, '%i')/5,0) as GRP, max(TS) MTS
             FROM CTE
             GROUP BY GRP) B
 On  A.TS = B.MTS

Giving us:
+--------+---------------------+
|  Name  |         TS          |
+--------+---------------------+
| bob    | 2024-05-05 13:00:00 |
| John   | 2024-05-05 13:08:00 |
| Denver | 2024-05-05 13:11:00 |
+--------+---------------------+

It essentially creates groups for every interval of 5 minutes picks the max timestamp for that interval and then joins it back the base set to get the user with that timestamp.  I use a join incase you want to include the groupings later.
It makes several assumptions:

we want to key off of minutes, not seconds
that having bob listed twice in results is an error 0-4.999 seconds would include only bob.  5 to 9.99 seconds would include ted, alice and john.
that a user in a different hour, day we'd pick the max of.  so if we need to group by different hours, days etc... then we need to edit the grouping.


The need to repeat the first row twice is not entirely clear to me. But if this doesn't count, we can split the table rows into 5-minute chunks. The query uses a dialect of Microsoft SQL Server.
select
  name, timestamp
from (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(
      partition by datediff(minute, 0, timestamp)/5*5
      order by timestamp desc
    ) as rn
  from example
) as t0
where rn = 1;

Result:
+---------+-------------------------+
|  name   |        timestamp        |
+---------+-------------------------+
| Bob     | 2024-05-05 15:00:00.000 |
| John    | 2024-05-05 15:08:00.000 |
| Denver  | 2024-05-05 15:11:00.000 |
+---------+-------------------------+

db<>fiddle
